# Are there AD issues when reconnecting a domain server that has been disconnected for an extended period of time?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2

I have two Windows Server 2008 R2 domain servers located in two physical locations connected via a VPN. They are functioning normally and syncing across the VPN. However, I intend to disable the VPN while I trace and fix extremely slow Internet access at one of the locations. This may take two or three weeks to allow time to monitor the network.

Am I going to have serious AD issues when I reconnect these two servers? I've never disconnected the servers for that long before and don't know what to expect.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794960(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read up on Tombstone in Active Directory. If you left the defaults alone in your GPO, then you  can break sync for up to 60 days* without tombstoning your DCs.

- (or 120 days, depending on the version of Windows that you built your domain with) (thanks Joe!)

Comment: If the domain was created with W2K8 R2 (or 2K8 or 2K3 SP1, but not 2K3 R2) then the tombstone lifetime should be 180 days.